# Can I open the native iOS/Android emoji keyboard from a textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a flutter app in which I want users to input an emoji to name an object. So, ideally I'd like to pull up the emoji keyboard when they click the field to enter the name.

I'm currently using `emoji_keyboard_flutter`, but it's not the native UI and isn't searchable. The native emoji keyboard can be accessed from any textfield, but it's not an available option for `keyboardType` Is there a way for me to trigger or navigate to the native emoji keyboard on iOS or Android when a user presses a button or focuses on a text field?

I see a few related questions, but none with answers.

Comment: Where you able to find out how to do this?